# Define element and attribute with restrictions

Tags: xml, xsd

I need to define XSD which has sequence of element with optional attribute. I also need to restrict string length of both element and attribute. Using following code I cannot seem to define 'restriction':

```
  <xs:element name="PeopleMentioned" minOccurs="0">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Person" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
              <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="PersonTopic" type="xs:string" />
              </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>                        
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

I need to restrict length of 'Person' and 'PersonTopic', like would normally do for simple type:

```
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:maxLength value="18" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To define both element and attribute with restrictions**, namely that `Person` and `PersonTopic` be strings of maximum length of 18:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            version="1.0">

  <xsd:element name="PeopleMentioned">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Person" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:simpleContent>
              <xsd:extension base="String18">
                <xsd:attribute name="PersonTopic" type="String18"/>
              </xsd:extension>
            </xsd:simpleContent>                        
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>

  <xsd:simpleType name="String18">  
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">  
      <xsd:maxLength value="18" />
    </xsd:restriction>  
  </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks @kjhughes. I needed separate length for both but based on your answer I defined two simple types (String18 and String50).